# boost: readline for tcp client

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, tcp, readline

I'm developing a tcp server in c++ using boost. I'd like process incoming data line by line and am looking for a socket.readLine method. However, I can only find a read_some() method. I don't what the definition on "some" is, but I don't think the string necessarily ends with a "\n".

So how can I implement socket.readLine() using boost?

Comment: you may want to check out async_read_until/read_until - there are examples of their use at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html (Http Client)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are using boost::asio. If so, there is a read_until() function that does what you want.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/read_until.html

Comment: The documentation seems to imply this: 
"This function is used to read data into the specified streambuf *until* the streambuf's get area contains the specified delimiter." 
(emphasis on *until* mine) 

In reality it will read more than that into the streambuf ...

Answer (score 2):

there is [`read_until`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/read_until.html)

Answer (score 2):

Use [boost::asio::read_until(..)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read_until/overload1.html).