# boost::asio::read_until does not accept a socket as an argument

Tags: c++, boost

I've [read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7878434/7622324) that you can use `boost::asio::read_until` to read from a socket, so I tried to do that:

```
using namespace boost::asio;
  ...
    boost::array<char, BUFFER_SIZE> buf;
    read_until(this->socket_opt.value(), buffer(buf), "\n");
```

But apparently, read_until cannot accept those arguments:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘read_until(const boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp>&, boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1, const char [2])’
        read_until(this->socket_opt.value(), buffer(buf), "\n");
```

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. socket_opt is defined as `std::optional<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket_opt` and has a value at runtime.

Comment: Is `read_until` being called within the context of a `const` member function?

Comment: @G.M. yeah, does that matter? The solution offered below worked.

Comment: @OmerLubin, @G.M, `read_until()` handles socket object and it could not be const. However, `std::optional::value()` has another overload which returns not const object, but in the above code, the const version was invoked since, I guess, the compilation failed anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`boost::asio::read_until()` requires dynamic buffer as second parameter.

I hope the following code helps you.

```
boost::asio::streambuf buf;
boost::asio::read_until(this->socket_opt.value(), buf, "\n");
```